# freezing issue in viber (ubuntu 22.04lts

Tags: boot, server

I am using ubuntu 22.04lts and I am facing an issue on viber  my viber frequently freeze  how to solve it I am using ubuntu 22.04lts and I am facing an issue on viber  my viber frequently freeze  how to solve it

Comment: How did you install Viber? Can you run `viber` from the command line and post the error message, if any?

Comment: i had installed viber using Command  and software and install saw successful but viber freezes while using

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi

Comment: Please provide more details about which command you used. Also, run `viber` from a terminal, and post the error messages by [editing](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1475631/edit) the question

Comment: Use the `free` terminal command to see if your system has swap space. Read `man mkswap swapon fallocate`.